# Stability of resonance structure

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance

My book states- " the one that has ...less separation of opposite charges ,...., more dispersal of charge is more stable than others"

Aren't 'less separation ' and 'more dispersal' opposite to each other?
Please explain with an example.

Comment: Why do you think that  _'less separation ' and 'more dispersal' opposite to each other_ ?

Answer (score 3):

Re-read the statement carefully. It says that the separation of opposite charges ("charge separation") destabilizes the resonating structures. The second phrase ("charge delocalisation") refers to the delocalisation of the *same* charge around a resonating structure.

For example, here's an example of how "charge delocalisation" increases stability:

[image]

(*[source](http://www.chem.ucla.edu/harding/tutorials/resonance/draw_res_str_key.html)*)
Notice the same positive charge is delocalised throughout the conjugated system. It reduces - the unit positive charge on a single carbon atom - to a partial positive charge over several carbon atoms in the resonance hybrid, thus increasing the stability of the molecule.

Here's an example of "charge separation":

[image]

which destabilises the molecule. Remember that uncharged structures are more stable than charged structures.

I hope it helps!